# cannot setVerticalTextPosition for JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have an icon with text for JLabel, I am trying to get the text to vertically positioned at the bottom, but this can't work, this is my whole class:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("my frame");
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JLabel label = new JLabel("my label");
        ImageIcon mouse = new ImageIcon("mouse.jpg");
        label.setIcon(mouse);
        label.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
        frame.add(label);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);


    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you provide whole class to copy paste and check it. Right now, your examples looks fine.

Comment: ok, I updated my class

Comment: I can see that `my label` in the bottom? Probably you want to move whole picture to the bottom?

Comment: Actually I was wondering how to move that text to the bottom below the picture, but how do you do both?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("my frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JLabel label = new JLabel("my label");
        ImageIcon mouse = new ImageIcon("mouse.jpeg");
        label.setIcon(mouse);
        label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
        frame.add(label);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);


    }
}
```

[image]

Reference:
[LabelTextPosition](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/LabelTextPosition.htm)

Comment: also add frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); so that application closes when you close the window, you can see multiple java instances are running in task manager